# "libcups2:amd64 cannot be configured because libcups2:i386 is in a different version"

Tags: dpkg

This is the output I get after issuing the command : `apt-get upgrade`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  duplicity
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
39 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
dpkg: error processing libcups2 (--configure):
 libcups2:amd64 1.5.3-0ubuntu8.2 cannot be configured because libcups2:i386 is in a different version (1.5.3-0ubuntu8)
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcupsmime1:
 libcupsmime1 depends on libcups2 (>= 1.5~); however:
  Package libcups2 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libcupsmime1 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcupscgi1:
 libcupscgi1 depends on libcups2 (>= 1.4.0); however:
  Package libcups2 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libcupscgi1 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                            dpkg: error processing libtiff4 (--configure):
 libtiff4:amd64 3.9.5-2ubuntu1.6 cannot be configured because libtiff4:i386 is in a different version (3.9.5-2ubuntu1.5)
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcupsimage2:
 libcupsimage2 depends on libcups2 (>= 1.4.0); however:
  Package libcups2 is not configured yet.
 libcupsimage2 depends on libtiff4; however:
  Package libtiff4 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libcupsimage2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcupsppdc1:
 libcupsppdc1 depends on libcups2 (>= 1.4.0); however:
  Package libcups2 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libcupsppdc1 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups-client:
 cups-client depends on libcups2 (>= 1.5.0); however:
  Package libcups2 is not configured yet.
 cups-client depends on libcupsimage2 (>= 1.4.0); however:
  Package libcuNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                             No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                                           No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                   No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                 No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                         No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                       No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                                                     No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                             No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                           No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                   No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                 No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
         psimage2 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing cups-client (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups-ppdc:
 cups-ppdc depends on libcups2 (>= 1.4.0); however:
  Package libcups2 is not configured yet.
 cups-ppdc depends on libcupsppdc1 (>= 1.4.0); however:
  Package libcupsppdc1 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing cups-ppdc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups:
 cups depends on libcups2 (>= 1.5.0); however:
  Package libcups2 is not configured yet.
 cups depends on libcupscgi1 (>= 1.4.2); however:
  Package libcupscgi1 is not configured yet.
 cups depends on libcupsimage2 (>= 1.4.0); however:
  Package libcupsimage2 is not configured yet.
 cups depends on libcupsmime1 (>= 1.5.0); however:
  Package libcupsmime1 is not configured yet.
 cups depends on libcupsppdc1 (>= 1.4.0); however:
  Package libcupsppdc1 is not configuredNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                      No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                            No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                                          No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                  No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                        No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                      No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                                                     yet.
 cups depends on cups-client (>= 1.5.3-0ubuntu8.2); however:
  Package cups-client is not configured yet.
 cups depends on cups-ppdc; however:
  Package cups-ppdc is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing cups (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:
 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 depends on libtiff4; however:
  Package libtiff4 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgtk2.0-0:
 libgtk2.0-0 depends on libcups2 (>= 1.4.0); however:
  Package libcups2 is not configured yet.
 libgtk2.0-0 depends on libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0); however:
  Package libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libgtk2.0-0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:
 google-chrome-stNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                               No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                                             No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                     able depends on libcups2 (>= 1.4.0); however:
  Package libcups2 is not configured yet.
 google-chrome-stable depends on libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0); however:
  Package libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 is not configured yet.
 google-chrome-stable depends on libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0); however:
  Package libgtk2.0-0 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing google-chrome-stable (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcupsdriver1:
 libcupsdriver1 depends on libcups2 (>= 1.4.0); however:
  Package libcups2 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libcupsdriver1 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgtk-3-0:
 libgtk-3-0 depends on libcups2 (>= 1.4.0); however:
  Package libcups2 is not configured yet.
 libgtk-3-0 depends on libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.25.2); however:
  Package libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libgtk-3-0 (--conNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                      figure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgail-3-0:
 libgail-3-0 depends on libgtk-3-0 (= 3.4.2-0ubuntu0.8); however:
  Package libgtk-3-0 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libgail-3-0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgail18:
 libgail18 depends on libgtk2.0-0 (= 2.24.10-0ubuntu6.1); however:
  Package libgtk2.0-0 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libgail18 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: error processing libmysqlclient18 (--configure):
 libmysqlclient18:amd64 5.5.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 cannot be configured because libmysqlclient18:i386 is in a different version (5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.04.2)
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-settings-daemon:
 gnome-settings-daemon depends on libcups2 (>= 1.4.0); however:
  Package libcups2 is not configured yet.
 gnome-settings-daemon depends on No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0); however:
  Package libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 is not configured yet.
 gnome-settings-daemon depends on libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.3.4); however:
  Package libgtk-3-0 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing gnome-settings-daemon (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of unity-greeter:
 unity-greeter depends on libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0); however:
  Package libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 is not configured yet.
 unity-greeter depends on libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.0.0); however:
  Package libgtk-3-0 is not configured yet.
 unity-greeter depends on gnome-settings-daemon; however:
  Package gnome-settings-daemon is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing unity-greeter (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of bluez-cups:
 bluez-cups depends on cups; however:
  Package cups is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing bluez-cups (--configure):
 dependency prNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                            oblems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgnome-control-center1:
 libgnome-control-center1 depends on libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.0.0); however:
  Package libgtk-3-0 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libgnome-control-center1 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of deja-dup:
 deja-dup depends on libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0); however:
  Package libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 is not configured yet.
 deja-dup depends on libgnome-control-center1 (>= 1:2.91.2); however:
  Package libgnome-control-center1 is not configured yet.
 deja-dup depends on libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.0.0); however:
  Package libgtk-3-0 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing deja-dup (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0:
 gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 depends on libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.25.2); however:
  Package libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 is not configNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                        ured yet.
dpkg: error processing gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gir1.2-gtk-2.0:
 gir1.2-gtk-2.0 depends on gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0; however:
  Package gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 is not configured yet.
 gir1.2-gtk-2.0 depends on libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0); however:
  Package libgtk2.0-0 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing gir1.2-gtk-2.0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gir1.2-gtk-3.0:
 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 depends on gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0; however:
  Package gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 is not configured yet.
 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 depends on libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.3.18); however:
  Package libgtk-3-0 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing gir1.2-gtk-3.0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-control-center:
 gnome-control-center depends on libcups2 (>= 1.4.0); howeNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                        ver:
  Package libcups2 is not configured yet.
 gnome-control-center depends on libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.23.0); however:
  Package libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 is not configured yet.
 gnome-control-center depends on libgnome-control-center1 (>= 1:3.3.5); however:
  Package libgnome-control-center1 is not configured yet.
 gnome-control-center depends on libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.3.6); however:
  Package libgtk-3-0 is not configured yet.
 gnome-control-center depends on gnome-settings-daemon (>= 3.3.91); however:
  Package gnome-settings-daemon is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing gnome-control-center (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gwibber-service:
 gwibber-service depends on gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0; however:
  Package gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing gwibber-service (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgwibber2:
 libgwibber2 depends on gwibber-service (>= 2.31.1); however:
  Package gwibber-service is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libgwibber2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgwibber-gtk2:
 libgwibber-gtk2 depends on libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0); however:
  Package libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 is not configured yet.
 libgwibber-gtk2 depends on libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.0.0); however:
  Package libgtk-3-0 is not configured yet.
 libgwibber-gtk2 depends on libgwibber2 (>= 3.3.90); however:
  Package libgwibber2 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libgwibber-gtk2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gwibber:
 gwibber depends on gir1.2-gtk-3.0; however:
  Package gir1.2-gtk-3.0 is not configured yet.
 gwibber depends on libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.0.0); however:
  Package libgtk-3-0 is not configured yet.
 gwibber depends on libgwibber-gtk2 (>= 3.1.4.1+r1119); howevNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                           er:
  Package libgwibber-gtk2 is not configured yet.
 gwibber depends on libgwibber2 (>= 3.1.4.1); however:
  Package libgwibber2 is not configured yet.
 gwibber depends on gwibber-service (= 3.4.2-0ubuntu2.4); however:
  Package gwibber-service is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing gwibber (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gwibber-service-facebook:
 gwibber-service-facebook depends on gwibber-service (>> 2.33.0); however:
  Package gwibber-service is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing gwibber-service-facebook (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gwibber-service-identica:
 gwibber-service-identica depends on gwibber-service (>> 2.33.0); however:
  Package gwibber-service is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing gwibber-service-identica (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems preveNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                             nt configuration of gwibber-service-twitter:
 gwibber-service-twitter depends on gwibber-service (>> 2.33.0); however:
  Package gwibber-service is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing gwibber-service-twitter (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgail-common:
 libgail-common depends on libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0); however:
  Package libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 is not configured yet.
 libgail-common depends on libgail18 (= 2.24.10-0ubuntu6.1); however:
  Package libgail18 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libgail-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgtk-3-bin:
 libgtk-3-bin depends on libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.4.2-0ubuntu0.8); however:
  Package libgtk-3-0 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libgtk-3-bin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgtk2.0-bin:
 libgtk2.0-bin depends on libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.24.10-0ubuntu6.1); however:
  Package libgtk2.0-0 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libgtk2.0-bin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of update-manager:
 update-manager depends on gir1.2-gtk-3.0; however:
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                Package gir1.2-gtk-3.0 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing update-manager (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of vino:
 vino depends on libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.0.0); however:
  Package libgtk-3-0 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing vino (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups-bsd:
 cups-bsd depends on libcups2 (>= 1.4.0); however:
  Package libcups2 is not configured yet.
 cups-bsd depends on cups-client (= 1.5.3-0ubuntu8.2); however:
  Package cups-client is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing cups-bsd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 libcups2
 libcupsmime1
 libcupscgi1
 libtiff4
 libcupsimage2
 libcupsppdc1
 cups-client
 cups-ppdc
 cups
 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
 libgtk2.0-0
 google-chrome-stable
 libcupsdriver1
 libgtk-3-0
 libgail-3-0
 libgail18
 libmysqlclient18
 gnome-settings-daemon
 unity-greeter
 bluez-cups
 libgnome-control-center1
 deja-dup
 gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0
 gir1.2-gtk-2.0
 gir1.2-gtk-3.0
 gnome-control-center
 gwibber-service
 libgwibber2
 libgwibber-gtk2
 gwibber
 gwibber-service-facebook
 gwibber-service-identica
 gwibber-service-twitter
 libgail-common
 libgtk-3-bin
 libgtk2.0-bin
 update-manager
 vino
 cups-bsd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have amd64 and i386 packages installed, you could try removing the i386 package:

```
dpkg -r libcups2:i386
dpkg --configure -a
```

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a

sudo apt-get install --reinstall libcups2 && sudo apt-get update
```

If problem still exists, run :

```
sudo apt-get install -f

sudo dpkg -r libcups2
```

If not yet resolved, run :

```
gksudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

In the resulting gedit, remove corrupted `libcups2` Package (all lines starts from `Package : libcups2`)